# Prevent popup from closing when you click outside iOS

Tags: ios, swift, modalviewcontroller

Im using present modaly segue "popupSegue"
i open it like this :

When click i call this :

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("popupSegue", sender: self)
```

And i open modal like this :

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if(segue.identifier == "popupSegue"){
        let smartPopupView = segue.destinationViewController as! SmartManagementPopupViewController
        prepareOverlayVC(smartPopupView)
    }
}

func prepareOverlayVC(overlayVC: UIViewController) {
    overlayVC.transitioningDelegate = overlayTransitioningDelegate
    overlayVC.modalPresentationStyle = .Custom
}
```

How i can disable dismissing popup when click outside ?

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: For swift: viewController.isModalInPresentation = true
Objective-C: viewController.modalInPresentation = YES; 

Worked for me like a charm!!